# C# Calculate SHA256 value for SEPA (XML) paymentfile

Tags: c#, xml, cryptography, sha256

in the specification of the "DFÜ agreement" is described to calculate the hashvalue for a SEPA container payment file by SHA256.

> The hash value is created using the entire contained document, including the opening 
>   and closing "document" tag.
>
> The document is canonised according to Canonical XML, version 1.0. 
>   (http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315).
>
> In the case of included documents, the canonisation has also to be executed according to the main document.
>
> SHA-256 is used as hash algorithm.
>
> The hash value is entered in hexadecimal form in the  tag, capital characters are used for the hexadecimal digits A to F. When using an XML container within the SRZ procedure it is mandatory to specify the hash value (the abbreviation SRZ 
>   stands for the German term „Servicerechenzentrum“ meaning “data processing service centre”).

I tryed different ways to do that but i am not able to get the correct value.

```
    [Test]
    public void GetHashTest()
    {
        // load document
        XmlDocument sepaContainer = new XmlDocument();
        sepaContainer.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        sepaContainer.Load("PathToFile");

        // do canonical 
        XmlDsigC14NTransform transformer = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        transformer.LoadInput(document);

        string compare = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte b in transformer.GetDigestedOutput(new SHA256Managed()))
        {
            compare += b.ToString("X2");
        }

        Assert.That(compare, Is.EqualTo("1FA8EE4F1E9551C82E1C7A82A88140325453A52BD08FF9FA5D13CA40F04AB305"));
    }
```

Also not working to read the file into a string and calculate:

```
    private string GetSHA256(string text)
    {
        UTF8Encoding UE = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

        SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();
        string hex = string.Empty;

        byte[] hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += string.Format("{0:X2}", x);
        }

        return hex;
    }
```

Currently i work with the SEPA XML container from here: http://entwickler-forum.de/showthread.php/64499-Auslesen-einer-XML-Datei

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<conxml xmlns="urn:conxml:xsd:container.nnn.002" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:conxml:xsd:container.nnn.002 container.nnn.002.xsd">
  <CreDtTm>2010-10-26T14:48:17Z</CreDtTm>
  <MsgPain008>
    <HashValue>38B862BD35B95D8CB20448153B5F6F73B3657EB1BC81CF11D3491D16EEA94009</HashValue>
    <HashAlgorithm>SHA256</HashAlgorithm>
    <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.008.002.01">
      <pain.008.001.01>
        <GrpHdr>
          <MsgId>D004201010261648081</MsgId>
          <CreDtTm>2010-10-26T14:48:08Z</CreDtTm>
          <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
          <CtrlSum>0.20</CtrlSum>
          <Grpg>MIXD</Grpg>
          <InitgPty>
            <Nm>Testauftraggeber SEPA-LS</Nm>
          </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <PmtInf>
          <PmtInfId>D00420101024444444081</PmtInfId>
          <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
          <PmtTpInf>
            <SvcLvl>
              <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
            </SvcLvl>
            <LclInstrm>
              <Cd>CORE</Cd>
            </LclInstrm>
            <SeqTp>OOFF</SeqTp>
          </PmtTpInf>
          <ReqdColltnDt>2010-11-02</ReqdColltnDt>
          <Cdtr>
            <Nm>Testauftraggeber SEPA-LS</Nm>
          </Cdtr>
          <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
              <IBAN>DE352505018444402014</IBAN>
            </Id>
          </CdtrAcct>
          <CdtrAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
              <BIC>SPKHDE2HXXX</BIC>
            </FinInstnId>
          </CdtrAgt>
          <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
          <DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
              <EndToEndId>Lastschriftreferenz 002</EndToEndId>
            </PmtId>
            <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">0.20</InstdAmt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
              <MndtRltdInf>
                <MndtId>Mandat002</MndtId>
                <DtOfSgntr>2010-10-26</DtOfSgntr>
                <AmdmntInd>false</AmdmntInd>
              </MndtRltdInf>
              <CdtrSchmeId>
                <Id>
                  <PrvtId>
                    <OthrId>
                      <Id>DE98ZZZ09999999999</Id>
                      <IdTp>SEPA</IdTp>
                    </OthrId>
                  </PrvtId>
                </Id>
              </CdtrSchmeId>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <DbtrAgt>
              <FinInstnId>
                <BIC>SPKHDE2HXXX</BIC>
              </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
              <Nm>Test Zahlungspflichtiger</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
              <Id>
                <IBAN>DE132505018005555552</IBAN>
              </Id>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <UltmtDbtr>
              <Nm>Test Miete</Nm>
            </UltmtDbtr>
            <RmtInf>
              <Ustrd>Test SEPA-LS Einzug durch 10002014 Zahlungspflichtiger 10002022</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
          </DrctDbtTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
      </pain.008.001.01>
    </Document>
  </MsgPain008>
</conxml>
```

I extracted the "Document"-node by hand and by xpath but still got a different value then there is calculated for the check hash.

Hopefully any of you has an idea?

EDIT: 26.08.2013 - changed (corrected) the given hashvalue of the xml file

Comment: Shouldn't the hash value be "7DDB2138E8C91037DA7A6E9552478C59A2AACE26F8112EBC8012A8DE11592025"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i want to inform about the solution, maybe any one will find these topic:
The document node has to selected directly in that way from the container: 
"XmlNodeList documentNodeList = sepaContainer.GetElementsByTagName("Document");"

then the outer xml of the first entry have to be canonized and convert to hash.

also the first posted value: 7DDB2138E8C91037DA7A6E9552478C59A2AACE26F8112EBC8012A8DE11592025
is wrong the correct value will be 38B862BD35B95D8CB20448153B5F6F73B3657EB1BC81CF11D3491D16EEA94009